# What is the use of DataLayer in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manger; here I can pass dynamic values using “Javascript Vaiables”. Can anybody explain where will be the use of “dataLayer” ? I think, all of those dynamic value requirements can be done by using “Javascript variable” itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two things come to mind:

- The Google Analytics transaction tracking requires a prefined dataLayer; that way you can use a simple tag template provided by Google instead of having to parse your own variable structure into something suitable
- it largely avoids variable naming collisions with other scripts; you only need to check if another script or global variable also uses the variable name "dataLayer". With lots of 'simple' variables you'd have to check with each one if them for collisions

So yes, you do not have to use the dataLayer variable, but it's much more convenient and simpler to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Eike's answer, the dataLayer *is* a javascript variable :-)

The main point as I see it is that some of the user interface bits and pieces are designed to work with a "dataLayer" variable to make your life easier.

For example with some tags/tag templates you can just tell GTM to use values from the dataLayer directly; if you used javascript variables you'd need to manually define macros for each variable and manually assign them to a tag rather than just use the data directly from the data layer.